# Android ignoring "reply-to" header

Tags: email, samsung

When I receive an email on my Samsung S5 and reply to it, the email is going to the sender's email instead of the requested "reply-to" email.

I am using the default email app that comes with the phone...  On my older S4 phone, the emails were properly going to the "reply-to" address.

How do I reply to the "reply-to" address instead of the sender's?

Android™ version 5.0.2, Lollipop (G900PVPU3BOK4)

Comment: Did you ever resolve this problem?